# update yiiwheels highchart via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highchart widget from yiiwheels (extension for Yii framework):

```
<?php $this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.highcharts.WhHighCharts',array(
'pluginOptions' => array(
            'title' => array('text' => 'Fruit Consumption'),
            'xAxis' => array('categories' => array('Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges')),
            'yAxis' => array('title' => array('text' => 'Fruit eaten')),
            'series' => array(
                array('name' => 'Jane', 'data' => array(1, 0, 4)),
                array('name' => 'John', 'data' => array(5, 7, 3))
            )
        )
    ));?>
echo TbHtml::button('Refresh Chart', array('id'=>'refreshButton')); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#refreshButton').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); // THIS IS NOT WORKING, HELP!!!
        chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5] ); // sample data
});
</script>
```

This works well if I use native highcharts.js from highcharts.com
But like I said, I use yiiwheels's highcharts widget.
How can I fix this, how to refer my chart from javascript/jquery?
Thanks

Comment: You can use redraw() function http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw

Comment: @sebastian I'm new to php & javascript so I use php widget. From other forum it looks like I need to use mixed between php and javascript to reload data with ajax. This is where I get confused :) Is there any method/callback from the widget itself to launch ajax and then render the result using redraw()?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. Better it using nativ javascript, instead of widget, and call ajax / series.update() funciton